# How can MSBuild detect the version of .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

In MSBuild project file (e.g., **.csproj*), I can detect if it is using .NET Core or .NET Framework or Mono by checking `MSBuildRuntimeType` property: `'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)'!='Core'`.  In the similar fashion, can I detect what version of .NET Core (e.g., `2.1`, `2.2`, `3.0`, `3.1`) is it?

Comment: MsBuild's MSBuildRuntimeType doesn't correspond to any .NET Core "detection". It just mean you're basically running MsBuild for .NET Core, or another one ("Mono", "Full"). See MsBuild source here: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/fa773bb8d44a358963481c02e772509dc408a6d9/src/Build/Evaluation/Evaluator.cs#L1140 it's hardcoded depending on how you compile MsBuild. Are you looking for the target framework/platform properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2019 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription.ToString();
```

This will return the version like this.

```
.NET Core 3.1.0
```

You can assign a property in MSBuild like this:

```
<MSBuildRuntimeVersion>$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]:: FrameworkDescription.ToString())</MSBuildRuntimeVersion>
```

### Update:

Based on @minhee's comment I came to know that the above solution is not working .NET Core 2.2 or older version. I did some research on this and found that it was a breaking change in CoreFx in which **[APIs that report version is now reporting product and not file version.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#apis-that-report-version-now-report-product-and-not-file-version)**

This thing is introduced in .NET Core 3.0 and I am not aware of that because I am not using .NET Core 2.2 or older.

With that said, I would like to propose another solution which is working with all versions of .NET Core.

```cs
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>().FrameworkName;
```

Here, you will get version number as below.

```
.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
```

I have tested this code with the following versions in a console application.

```cs
.NET Core 2.0
.NET Core 2.1
.NET Core 2.2
.NET Core 3.0
.NET Core 3.1
```

### In MSBuild:

You can check the same thing in the MSBuild also.

For example, In the below .csproj file I have defined the two message tasks based on the condition of the target framework. So, If I build the project with the target framework as `netcoreapp2.2` then it will print *"Happy 2020..."* in build log and if I build the project with target framework as `netcoreapp3.0` then it will print *"Happy New Year..."* in the build log.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Target Name="FooName" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v3.0'">
        <Message Text="Happy New Year..." Importance="High" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="FooName" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v2.2'">
        <Message Text="Happy 2020..." Importance="High" />
    </Target>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>New_folder</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So, you can use `TargetFrameworkVersion` property to detect the current version of .NET Core in the MSBuild.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: On .NET Core 2.2 it seems to return an incorrect version string: `.NET Core 4.6.28207.03`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes MSB4185 error as `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` method does not seem included in MSBuild's safe function list.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `Reflection` only instead you have an option with MSBuild condition?

Comment: Could you elaborate on having an option with MSBuild condition?

Comment: I am talking about `Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v3.0'"` in `.csproj`. Is there any specific reason for not going with this approach?

Comment: `'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'` seems just evaluated to an empty string.

Comment: You may be doing something wrong. Have you checked the MsBuild logs? How you have used that property?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `$([System.Environment]::Version)`
e.g.

```
<Message Importance="High" Text="$([System.Environment]::Version)" />
<Message Importance="High" Text="$([System.Environment]::Version.Major)" />
```

Works for NetFramework and Net6 (which is what I have available locally)